# How can I remotely execute the ListBox1_DoubleClick event of a ListBox using WinApi/user32.dll or something similar?

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

I need to invoke the ListBox1_DoubleClick event from another application.

Look below how I think that should be the code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class RemoteControl
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    public void SendClickLB(string sWinTitle, int iChildHandler)
    {
        var windowHWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, windowTitle);
        var childWindows = GetChildWindows(windowHWnd);
        IntPtr hWnd = childWindows.ToArray()[index];

        const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;

        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @EdPlunkett, many thanks for your help. 
I am already using the ListBox Handler, as for sending the coordinates in param lParam I will see how to do this.
However with WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK it hasn't worked yet.

Comment: That's probably not geat advice. Use UI Automation.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I can get the ListBox handler, I can even get the text of an Item with LB_GETTEXT, but ListBox events I still can't figure out how to trigger them.

Comment: Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: Thanks, guys, I'll study UI Automation and make use of it to solve my problem as soon as I can inform you.
thank you so much for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trigger the ListBox's DbClick event remotely using user32.dll.

The steps I used to reach the expected result were as follows:

1 - First I had to get the X, Y coordinates through the Listbox handle using the ClientToScreen (hWnd, ref point) function;

2 - After I got through the coordinates obtained to move the mouse to the desired position and send the DoubleClick using the function mouse_event (MouseEventFlag dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

Many Thanks.